# "Schlaf mir nicht ein" - warum "mir"?

Tags: usage

Wie kann man denn genau die Verwendung von *"mir"* in einem Satz wie *"Schlaf mir nicht ein!"* erklären? Auf Englisch würde mir sowas wie *"Don't you quit on me!"* einfallen, aber auch da hätte ich leichte Probleme die genaue Bedeutungsnuance zu erklären.

Comment: Mir fällt dazu noch ein, dass "mir" in diesem Zusammenhang auch häufig mit "ja" steht: "Schlaf mir ja nicht ein!"

Comment: Die Bezeichnung hierfür ist _ethischer Dativ_.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

"Mir" hat oft die Bedeutung von "für mich".

Sing mir das vor! Schreib mir das auf! etc.

Mit einer Negation bedeutet es hier, dass du mir zuliebe nicht einschlafen sollst, oder dass ich mich dafür verantwortlich fühlen würde oder dafür verantwortlich gemacht werden würde (wie auch im englischen Beispielsatz). Das ganze wird gerne auch passiv-aggressiv verwendet, um anzudeuten, dass man eine Handlung der anderen Person als gegen sich selbst gerichtet interpretiert:

Du heiratest mir nicht dieses Flittchen!

Comment: +1 für das schöne passiv-aggressive Beispiel :)

Answer (score 5):

Nach meinem Empfinden ist der Satz auf folgende Weise zu interpretieren:

> Schlaf jetzt nicht ein, sonst muss ich mich mit den Folgen beschäftigen oder muss mir Sorgen machen.

Das lässt sich auch auf andere Aussagen anwenden, die häufig mit "mir" verwendet werden:

> Mach mir keine Schande!

Heißt in etwa: *"Handle so, dass ich mich später nicht schämen muss."*